# Optimizing this query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

since oracle does not support null=null comparisons I did this statement:

```
SELECT p.nazwa,
       p.nazwa_miedz,
       p.dawka_l_p,
       p.dawka_j_p,
       p.dawka_l_n,
       p.dawka_j_n
FROM   produkt p
WHERE  p.nazwa_miedz LIKE (SELECT pp.nazwa_miedz
                           FROM   produkt pp
                           WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296)
       AND p.bloz12 != (SELECT pp.bloz12
                        FROM   produkt pp
                        WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296)
       AND ( p.dawka_l_p = (SELECT pp.dawka_l_p
                            FROM   produkt pp
                            WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296)
              OR ( p.dawka_l_p IS NULL
                   AND (SELECT pp.dawka_l_p
                        FROM   produkt pp
                        WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296) IS NULL ) )
       AND ( p.dawka_j_p = (SELECT pp.dawka_j_p
                            FROM   produkt pp
                            WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296)
              OR ( p.dawka_j_p IS NULL
                   AND (SELECT pp.dawka_j_p
                        FROM   produkt pp
                        WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296) IS NULL ) )
       AND ( p.dawka_l_n = (SELECT pp.dawka_l_n
                            FROM   produkt pp
                            WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296)
              OR ( p.dawka_l_n IS NULL
                   AND (SELECT pp.dawka_l_n
                        FROM   produkt pp
                        WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296) IS NULL ) )
       AND ( p.dawka_j_n = (SELECT pp.dawka_j_n
                            FROM   produkt pp
                            WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296 IS NULL)
              OR p.dawka_j_n IS NULL
                 AND (SELECT pp.dawka_j_n
                      FROM   produkt pp
                      WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296) )
```

What this statemtent do? Shows us replacement for medicine. bloz12 = 232440132296 is id of product. We are looking for products which has the same doses: dawka_l_p,dawka_j_p,dawka_l_n, dawka_j_n. There is also one AND to do not show the replacement (which be the same as original product). And the last AND nazwa_miedz is just the substance of medicine. Im just wondering if those subquerys can be optimized.. As You can see there is many of them.. I hope someone could improve it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.nazwa,
   p.nazwa_miedz,
   p.dawka_l_p,
   p.dawka_j_p,
   p.dawka_l_n,
   p.dawka_j_n

FROM produkt p join product p2 on p.nazwa_miedz = p2.nazwa_miedz
and (p.dawka_l_p = p2.dawka_l_p or
     p.dawka_l_p is NULL and p2.dawka_l_p is NULL)
and (p.dawka_j_p = p2.dawka_j_p or
     p.dawka_j_p is NULL and p2.dawka_j_p is NULL)
and (p.dawka_l_n = p2.dawka_l_n or
     p.dawka_l_n is NULL and p2.dawka_l_n is NULL)
and (p.dawka_j_n = p2.dawka_j_n or
     p.dawka_j_n is NULL and p2.dawka_j_n is NULL)
WHERE p.bloz12 != 232440132296
and p2.bloz12 = 232440132296
```

I'm guessing you have forgotten to add an `is NULL` at the end of

```
...
OR p.dawka_j_n IS NULL
    AND (SELECT pp.dawka_j_n
        FROM   produkt pp
        WHERE  pp.bloz12 = 232440132296)
```

?

When [comparing NULL values](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF51097) remember that e.g `p.dawka_j_n = p2.dawka_j_n` will not evaluate to true when both are `NULL` so explicitly checking  with `is NULL` is necessary if that's what you want.

Comment: `on p.nazwa_miedz = p2.nazwa_miedz` should be: `on p.nazwa_miedz LIKE p2.nazwa_miedz`

Comment: @ypercube yes, ure right about this;
And You're right too. I noticed it just know, i think i cut it with accident

Comment: @binotemary: great! it works:) and is more readable that mine version :) Thank You very much for help :)

Comment: @ypercube: I think using `LIKE` would make sense only if `nazwa_miedz` column contains wildcard characters (_, %), because the right side of `LIKE` is a pattern to match. And if the pattern doesn't contain wildcards then it basically just checks for equality.

Answer (score 1):

A self join will probably work.  This will show you the general idea.

```
    SELECT p.nazwa,
       p.nazwa_miedz,
       p.dawka_l_p,
       p.dawka_j_p,
       p.dawka_l_n,
       p.dawka_j_n

FROM   produkt p join product p2 on p.dawka_l_p = p2.dawka_l_p
and p.dawka_j_p = p2.dawka_j_p
and p.dawka_l_n = p2.dawka_l_n

WHERE p.bloz12 <> 232440132296
and p2.bloz12 = 232440132296
```

There might be some details that I missed.

Comment: Hmm.. Something wrong with it, returns me 0 rows, when my query returns everything what I wanted.. Still thinking why does not work, because for me it seems logical :)

Comment: Maybe some of those ands should be ors.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30ce5/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE produkt (
  bloz12      NUMBER(20),
  nazwa       NUMBER(20),
  nazwa_miedz VARCHAR2(20),
  dawka_l_p   NUMBER(5,2),
  dawka_j_p   NUMBER(5,2),
  dawka_l_n   NUMBER(5,2),
  dawka_j_n   NUMBER(5,2)
);

INSERT INTO produkt
          SELECT 232440132296, 1, 'Reference Sample', 1,1,1,1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1, 'Reference Sample', 1,1,1,1 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT p.nazwa,
       p.nazwa_miedz,
       p.dawka_l_p,
       p.dawka_j_p,
       p.dawka_l_n,
       p.dawka_j_n
FROM   produkt p
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                FROM   produkt x
                WHERE  x.bloz12 = 232440132296
                AND    p.bloz12 <> x.bloz12
                AND    p.nazwa_miedz LIKE x.nazwa_miedz
                AND    (  p.dawka_l_p = x.dawka_l_p
                       OR (   p.dawka_l_p IS NULL
                          AND x.dawka_l_p IS NULL ) )
                AND    (  p.dawka_j_p = x.dawka_j_p
                       OR (   p.dawka_j_p IS NULL
                          AND x.dawka_j_p IS NULL ) )
                AND    (  p.dawka_l_n = x.dawka_l_n
                       OR (   p.dawka_l_n IS NULL
                          AND x.dawka_l_n IS NULL ) )
                AND    (  p.dawka_j_n = x.dawka_j_n
                       OR (   p.dawka_j_n IS NULL
                          AND x.dawka_j_n IS NULL ) ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30ce5/1/0)**:

```
| NAZWA |      NAZWA_MIEDZ | DAWKA_L_P | DAWKA_J_P | DAWKA_L_N | DAWKA_J_N |
|-------|------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     1 | Reference Sample |         1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |
```

Comment: Problem is that I have about 300 000 rows in this column.. What is weird this query is executing in 300-400sec, where mine is 0.132sec..